# 13.10 - Samba mount error: Could not resolve address

Tags: 13.10, mount, samba, fstab, shared-folders

**Basically, in Ubuntu 13.10 I can't mount a shared folder via the terminal nor fstabs, yet can access the shared folder via Nautilus and `smbclient`**

I recently upgraded from Linux Mint 15 to Ubuntu 13.10.
I have a PC with a shared folder created via Windows Groups, that I could samba via a samba client from my old Mint laptop.
But now that I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, I can't seem to mount it.

What seems weird to me, is that when using Nautilus, I can access the shared folder just fine (via "Browse Network"), and can also access it directly with `smbclient` , but I can't mount it with `sudo mount` , nor can set it to be automatically mounted at boot by adding the corresponding entry to `fstab`

I'll add more info. In my PC, I have Windows 7. The folder I'm sharing is a specific drive ("D:" in my case).
Like I said, when using Nautilus I can open it and access it just fine.

Also, when I try using the samba client, I can also access it fine:

`smbclient "//gonzalo-pc/Disco D" -U [Win7 user]`

`[Win7 user]` being my user from Windows 7 in my PC

By executing this command (after introducing the password when it prompts me), I get the `smb: >` prompt, and by doing `dir` I can see every folder in my Win7 "D:" Drive, so it works.

However, when I use the following command to try and mount it, it doesn't work:

`sudo mount -t cifs "//gonzalo-pc/Disco D"  /mnt/share`

`/mnt/share` being a directory I created to set up the mount.

When I execute the above command, I get the following error:

`mount error: could not resolve address for gonzalo-pc: Unknown error`

I don't know what is causing this, since I don't see how the address "gonzalo-pc" can not be resolved, since it is resolved fine when accessing it via Nautilus or `smbclient`

Moreover, I can't mount it by adding an entry to fstab either.
The entry is the following one:

```
//GONZALO-PC/Disco\040D /mnt/share cifs username=[Win7 User],credentials=/home/gonzalo
/.smbcredentials,uid=[Ubuntu user],nbrl 0 0
```

I have a file at `~/.smbcredentials` with the following format:

```
username=[Win7 user]
password=[Win7 password]
```

I am not sure exactly what is going wrong. In my previous Linux Mint installation, I followed similar steps and could mount it (the exact same shared folder) fine.

Answer (score 3):

the CIFS module only supports DNS names, not NetBIOS names (which I suspect gonzalo-pc is). Try replacing 'gonzalo-pc' in the CIFS mount command with the IP address of the machine.